# How to handle custom protocol detection in Javascript for Firefox, Opera and Safari browsers?

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-browser, dom-events, angular8

I have used code to handle custom protocol for various browsers, but its not working for Firefox, Opera and Safari. Please help me out with this.

Please check below is my code I have used.

For firefox version >= 64

```
const openUriWithHiddenFrame = (uri, failCb, successCb) => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      failCb();
      handler.remove();
    }, DEFAULT_CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_FAIL_CALLBACK_TIMEOUT);

    let iframe = document.querySelector("#hiddenIframe");
    if (!iframe) {
      iframe = createHiddenIframe(document.body, "about:blank");
    } 

    const handler = registerEvent(window, "blur", () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      handler.remove();
      successCb();
    });

    iframe.contentWindow.location.href = uri;
  };
```

For Firefox Version < 64

```
const openUriUsingFirefox = (uri, failCb, successCb) => {
    let iframe = document.querySelector("#hiddenIframe");
    if (!iframe) {
      iframe = createHiddenIframe(document.body, "about:blank");
    }

    try {
      iframe.contentWindow.location.href = uri;
      successCb();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.name == "NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL") {
        failCb();
      }
    }
  };
```

For Opera and Safari

In case of Opera, If application exists then it asks for whether to open but when not exists it shows unknown protocol instead of fail call back.

```
const openUriWithTimeoutHack = (uri, failCb, successCb) => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      failCb();
      handler.remove();
    }, DEFAULT_CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_FAIL_CALLBACK_TIMEOUT);

    // Handle page running in an iframe (blur must be registered with top level window)
    let target = window;
    while (target.parent && target != target.parent) {
      target = target.parent;
    }

    const handler = registerEvent(target, "blur", () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      handler.remove();
      successCb();
    });  

    window.location = uri;
  };
```

Comment: What exactly is not working and what are you trying to do? You can get the protocol of a URL using `new URL(uri).protocol`

Comment: I need to detect whether custom protocol supported application exist in my system or not. If found then should ask to open the application else then redirect to download URL which will handled in case fail call back.
For ex: the uri is cust://something then whether "cust" supported application exists or not.

Comment: @KarthikP Hi here did you get the information that "iframe.contentWindow.location.href = uri;" only works for ff <63 ?

Comment: Can you share piece of code what you have written in "successCb()" and "failcb()"?